# Is it ok to register the Ninject kernel in the kernel itself?

Tags: c#, ninject, inversion-of-control

I have a troublesome Windows service ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674590/how-to-use-ninject-in-a-multi-threaded-windows-service-to-get-new-instances-of-a)), and I am considering creating a custom scope factory to generate a new scope each time the service ticks.

I plan to inject the kernel into this factory, so that it can return a new scope for the service on every tick and destroy / release the scope after each tick.

To facilitate this, I plan to added this to my RegisterServices() method:

`kernel.Bind<IKernel>().ToConstant(kernel);`

And my custom scope factory would look like this:

```
public class CustomScopeFactory : ICustomScopeFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;

    public CustomScopeFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public ICustomScope CreateScope()
    {
        return kernel.Get<ICustomScope>();
    }

    public void DisposeScope(ICustomScope scope)
    {
        kernel.Release(scope);
    }
}
```

I wouldn’t usually consider registering the kernel in the kernel or injecting it, but in this scenario I think it is a valid use case.

So, is it ok to register the Ninject kernel in the kernel itself? Any thoughts or alternatives would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is any different to a normal _Service Locator_.. since you're injecting the container itself. Your alternative is to inject an `IDependencyResolver` or something similar .. making it container independent (if that's what you're aiming for).

Comment: Instead of the `IKernel` interface, you can use the `IResolutionRoot` interface. I think it's already registered so you don't even need to create a binding for it.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit what's the benefit of using the ````IResolutionRoot```` instead of ````IKernel````?

Comment: @Kevin Kuszyk `IKernel` is basically `IBindingRoot` + `IResolutionRoot` + `IDisposable`. So a) you don't need `IBindingRoot`, so why make it accessible? b) you most certainly don't want to dispose the kernel you get injected, or you will end up disposing the kernel many times over. But its not good practice to use disposables and not dispose them. c) you don't need to bind `IResolutionRoot`, but you need to bind `IKernel` (edit: i'm not 100% certain about this).

Comment: Instead of using `kernel.Release(scope)` you can also have `ICustomScope` implement `INotifyWhenDisposed` and dispose the scope. That way you don't need the `ICustomScopeFactory` to end a scope. Also Code Analysis (FxCop) can help you ensure that disposing of a `IDisposable` is done properly - that would not be the case for `ICustomScopeFactory.DisposeScope(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, is it ok to register the Ninject kernel in the kernel itself?

Yes, there is no problem with this. Injecting the kernel into classes is fine, as long as those classes are located in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). Injecting the kernel into classes that are located outside the Composition Root leads to the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/), while injecting into classes that are placed inside the Composition root is [merely mechanics](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics/).

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to register the `IKernel`. It is automatically injected for any container-created classes that have a `IKernel` dependency (constructor, field or property).

Comment: I checked the [source](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/KernelBase.cs#L91-L92) and both the `IKernel` and `IResolutionRoot` are already registered.

Comment: Exactly, they are already provided by Ninject upon activating an instance that has a dependency on `IKernel` or `IResolutionRoot`.