# How to reinject an EF context when using contructor dependency injection with Ninject?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I am injecting all dependencies (services, context) through the contructor with the help of Ninject. The scope of all dependencies is for the current request. Everything works ok but now I want in some case to refresh/reconstruct the Entity Framework context. So basically I just want a dependency reinjected.

I could inject an UnitofWork and call some method on it to remake the context. For Entity Framework this means creating another context. But I am wondering if Ninject will be aware of this and what happens if I further need to use the context in the same request - will it use the old or new context?

Comment: Can you explain when you need to 'refresh' the Unit of work?

Comment: @Steven: In a controller action.

Comment: I asked "when" not "where" :-). What I mean by this is, *in what situation* do you need to refresh your unit of work?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge ninject does not provide an implementation for what you specifically need.

In your case it might make sense that the client code controls the lifecycle of the ´DbContext´ explicitly. Instead of injecting the ´DbContext´ you would inject an ´IDbContextFactory´. You would need to pass the db context to everyone who will require the same instance.

I've worked on a fairly complicated SW where it was done like this.
However we've gone a step further: As a facilitation, we stored the unit of work (`DataContext`) in a ´ThreadLocal´. This limits your software in that you can't share the unit of work across multiple threads. However this is usually something you should not do anyway since a transaction should be as short as possible.

The benefit is that then you don't need to pass around the unit of work reference all the time, instead, you create an adapter which you can inject freely and which you use to access the current ThreadLocal's value whenever you need to access the unit of work.
You will still need to explicitly control the lifecycle of the unit of work, though. So you still need the factory which will instanciate the unit of work and assign it to the ´ThreadLocal´. At the end of the unit of work, you commit or rollback and then you reset the ´ThreadLocal´.

Also see this answer which also contains code:
[How to use Ninject in a multi-threaded Windows service to get new instances of a dependency (DbContext) on every tick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674590/how-to-use-ninject-in-a-multi-threaded-windows-service-to-get-new-instances-of-a/21676963#21676963)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you either need inject a DbContext factory class, or you could inject a Func< DbContext > and have Ninject resolve this as a method.